# How do I set up a rolling 7 day 75th percentile in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, aggregate-functions, window-functions, percentile

I have a table that has the following columns:

- Event Date
- Location
- Employee Id
- Task Name
- Volume Per Hour

Using `PostgreSQL`, I need to **calculate the 75th percentile of Volume Per Hour for a given location and task name across all employee ids and event dates assuming a rolling 7 day window**. For example, if the event date is 11/16/2020, I would take the 75th percentile of volume per hour for all the individual dates and employee ids between 11/09/2020 and 11/16/2020.
Can someone help me with this problem?

Sample Data:

[image: Sample Data]

Sample Output:

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: You tagged amazon redshift, but mentioned postgres in your question.

Comment: Welcome here @user14652614 . In order to help us to support you, please provide a more simple explanation about what you need to do as we may do not understand your domain terms. If you provide some formulas for your calculation will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this by using [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-srf.html) and [`percentile_disc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-aggregate.html)

```sql
with data_example as
(
 SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
 (date '2020-11-16','ABC',1,'Inbound',10),
 (date '2020-11-16','ABC',2,'Inbound',20),
 (date '2020-11-15','ABC',1,'Inbound',30),
 (date '2020-11-17','ABC',1,'Inbound',10)
 ) AS t (event_date,location,emp_id,task_name,volume)
)
,dates as
(
select generate_series(
           (date '2020-11-10')::timestamp,
           (date '2020-11-25')::timestamp,
           interval '1 day'
         ) as event_date
)
select d.event_date
, d.event_date - INTERVAL '7 day' AS window_start
,location
,task_name
,percentile_disc(0.75) within group (order by de.volume) perc_volume
,count(1) cnt
from dates d
join data_example de
    on de.event_date between d.event_date- INTERVAL '7 day' and d.event_date
group by 1,2,3,4
order by 1,2,3,4;
```

Comment: Your approach of joining between event_date-7 and event_date worked great in getting a trailing 7 day window at a daily level. This worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Great to hear, could you mark this as answer then, and welcome to the community